# How to generate logarithmic/ Trigonometric tables in mathematica

Tags: list-manipulation

I was looking for ways to create logarithmic / trigonometric tables in *Mathematica*. And printing them for use . Here the tables should be like standard log tables with mean differences column .
I don't seem to get a way to do with the Table Command.
What I mean is to generate tables like-
[image]

Comment: Differences between what?

Comment: I think I understood what the OP is asking and I have made an answer for that but unable to post.I believe he is asking about the Common logarithm table where we find the mantissa and mean difference. i made a code to generate that table. Can someone open this post. Also why can't questions which are put on hold be answered.It maybe unclear to the majority but there could be someone who understood it and wants to answer.

Comment: @Hubble07 Yeh I mean the same

Answer (score 3):

The code below can reproduce the Log Table shown [here](http://www.girishgovindan.com/uploads/mt/Log_Antilog.pdf).

```
logTable[upto_] := Module[{},

 mantissa[num_] := 
 Flatten[{num, 
 Table[Rationalize[FractionalPart[N[Log10[num*10 + j], 5]]], {j, 
   0, 9}]}];

 meanDiff[num_] := Module[{},
 Table[
 Round[Total[
    Table[N[Log10[num*100 + i*10 + j], 6] - 
      N[Log10[num*100 + i*10], 6], {i, 0, 9}]]*10^3], {j, 1, 
  9}]];

 g1 = Grid[
 Partition[
 Flatten[Join[Flatten[Join[{"Log", Range[0, 9]}]], 
   mantissa[#] & /@ Range[10, upto]]], 11], Frame -> All];

 g2 = Grid[
 Partition[
 Flatten[Join[{Range[9], meanDiff[#] & /@ Range[10, upto]}]], 9], 
 Frame -> All];

 Row[{g1, g2}]

 ]
```

The argument to the function is the integer (10 - 99) up-to which you want to generate the table.

```
logTable[15]
```

[image]

Comment: You don't need to create new anonymous functions when mapping named functions, like `foo[#] & /@ bar`.  You can simply use `foo /@ bar`.

Answer (score 2):

I´m not sure whether I understood you right, but a simple table can be created via, e.g.

```
Table[{x, Log[x]}, {x, 1, 2, 0.05}] // TableForm
```

with Grid you can produce this a bit more "stylish":

```
out = Table[{x, Log[x]}, {x, 1, 2, 0.05}]; 
Grid[Prepend[out, {"x", "Log[x]}"}], Frame -> All]
```

Furthermore you can use all the "Style" options to brush this up.

Comment: I mean the tables we get with the mean differences and all .

Comment: Please give us a detailed description of the table entries you seek... otherwise we'll all waste time on this request.